# SharePoint 2010 Development: PrincipalContext Could not be Found

Tags: 2010, active-directory

I am using Visual Studio 2010. When I want to use PrincipalContext Class, the Visual Studio couldn't find the Reference:

[image]

I have opened the project with .NET Framework 4 selected and my project was targeting .NET Framework 3.5 in Project Properties.

.NET Framework 3.5+ should have System.DirectoryServices but why this happens?

*PS: I am using **Application page**.*

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.DirectoryServies.AccountManagement in your project? Are you using that namespace in your code file?

Comment: There is no "System.DirectoryServies" in Reference List to Add! I have no idea what's happening...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think System.DirectoryServices requires an manual reference to System.DirectoryServices.dll which can be done just by right clicking your project in solution explorer -> Add Reference -> in .NET Tab,

select "System.DirectoryServies.AccountManagement".

Now, you should be able to import System.DirectoryServies.AccountManagement namespace.

[image: Adding Reference to System.DirectoryServies.AccountManagement]

If you still can't see it like its shown in above picture then you should try adding reference like this,

```
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

It doesn't matter if you are using application page or not, I would recommend you to go through [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38344/Using-System-DirectoryServices-AccountManagement) for a better understanding of this new class for Directory services.

Hope it helps.